# Gatling - Scala extract substring

Tags: scala, gatling

I have extracted a string from the HTML response body using the below REGEX code

```
.check(regex("pzTransactionId=.*pzFromFrame").find.saveAs("pzTransId"))
```

Extracted value is `pzTransactionId=1g2h3j1h2g35k6j4lnx93jsn83jsn1e&pzFromFrame`

But I need a substring from the extracted value which is `g2h3j1h2g35k6j4lnx93jsn83jsn1e`. How do I do that? I need this value so that I can pass it in subsequent request. I tried the below options but it did not work.

```
.exec{session
val pztransactionid = (session("pzTransId").as[String].substring(0,5))}
```

But if I print `pztransactionid` it says value is not available in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, it should be:

```
.check(regex(".*pzTransactionId=(.*)&pzFromFrame.*").find.saveAs("pzTransId"))
```

I recommend you read [Java regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation, in particular capture groups.